# Swift 3 - Core Data Saving with one-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working with core data and i have two entity:

SwimmingPool
Parameters
Each swimming pool can have multiple parameters

[image: relation between swimming pool and parameters]

[image: swimming pool entity]

[image: parameters entity]

I have already saved and fetched data for swimming pool.

I've saved them trough a form.

In my AppDelegate i have:

```
let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = ad.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

and here's the func:

```
 var swimmingpool: SwimminPool!

    if swimmingPoolToEdit == nil {
        swimming = SwimminPool(context: context)
    } else {
        swimming = swimmingPoolToEdit
    }

    if let name =  swimmingName.text {
        swimming.name = name
    }
    if let volume = swimmingVolume.text {
        swimming.volume = volume
.........................................................
ad.saveContext()
```

and i perform the fetch like so:

```
var controller: NSFetchedResultsController<SwimmingPool>!

func attemptFetch() {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<SwimminPool> = SwimminPool.fetchRequest()
    let dataSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dataSort]

     let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    controller.delegate = self
    self.controller = controller

    do {
        try controller.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let error = error as NSError
        print("\(error.debugDescription)")
    }
}
```

Through a segue i pass all the data to a new controller and through a new form (in an another controller) i'm trying to save the data for the parameters and connect them to the the specific swimming pool.

Do i need to save the data like i did for the swimming pool and the relationship will automatically connect the two entities or do i need to connect them upon saving?

I'm new to swift and i'm not sure how to save related datas

The connection will be made upon saving or when i will perform the parameters fetch?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Create **Parameter** managed object and then link this parameter to a **SwimingPool** managed object:

```
let parameter = Parameters(context: context)
parameter.chlorum = Double(12245454.12211) // insert your value
parameter.oxigen = "your value here"
parameter.createdAt = "your value here"

let swimming = SwimminPool(context: context)
swimming.parameter = parameter
ad.saveContext()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add `Parameters` to a specific `SwimmingPool`

- In the segue pass the specific `SwimmingPool` instance to the form controller.
- Create `Parameters` instances by inserting them into the context.
- Add the relationship to the `SwimmingPool` instance by calling `insert` on the `parameter` attribute / relationship or the generated accessor `addToParameter` of the `NSManagedObject` subclass.
- Save the context. (important as **last** step).

Note : To avoid confusion name an `Entity` always in singular form (e.g. `SwimmingPool` / `Parameter`), a one-to-one relationship also in singular form (e.g. `parameter`) and  a one-to-many relationship in plural form (e.g. `parameters`)

PS: You question is ambiguous: You are writing *Each swimming pool can have multiple parameters* but the model design is *Each parameter can have multiple swimming pools*

Comment: Thx!!!! i think i did it.... if i may ask one more question it would be great... now cani fetch those data normally? i mean like i did for the aquarium? or do i have to specify the relationship?

Comment: You can fetch the `Swimmingpool` records and get the parameters from the `parameter` attribute / relationship or fetch the `Parameter` records and get their pool from the `swimmingPool` attribute / relationship.

Comment: ok i think i understand... i'll try later! finger cross! Thx!

Comment: i was sure it was correct.... my mistake i have to change the model than... i have to make each swimming pool to have many parameters... this should be correct now: [image](https://prnt.sc/ftqxwn) right?

Comment: Yes but – once again – you should name the *one-to-many relationship in plural form (`parameters`)*

Comment: Right.... i'll change it right away... thx! :) now i'll try to perform the fetch..